# How to add surcharge

Tags: wordpress, date, datepicker, woocommerce

I have this process, the user selects 2 dates. The system will then check if there are weekends. Weekends are:

- Friday
- Saturday
- Sunday

Every time there are weekends, there would be additional charge + $10 PER DAY OF THE WEEKEND.

I have this code below, what I want is the process to add the surcharge.

http://jsfiddle.net/xtD5V/71/

```
function isWeekend(date1, date2) {
    var d1 = new Date(date1),
        d2 = new Date(date2), 
        isWeekend = false;

    while (d1 < d2) {
        var day = d1.getDay();
        isWeekend = (day == 6) || (day == 0);
        if (isWeekend) { return true; }
        d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return false;
}

alert(isWeekend(date1, date2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can opt to try this option.

- Loop through all the dates and check for weekends like you did.
- Store it in a variable

**Option 1:**

```
function noOfWeekends(date1, date2) {
    //record number of weekends
    var no_of_weekends = 0;

    var d1 = new Date(date1),
    d2 = new Date(date2), 
    isWeekend = false;

while (d1 < d2) {
    var day = d1.getDay();
    isWeekend = (day == 6) || (day == 0);
    if (isWeekend) { no_of_weekends++; }
    d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + 1);
}

return no_of_weekends;

}

//noOfWeekends now returns the number of weekends. You can do more stuff with it
alert(noOfWeekends(date1, date2) > 0);
alert("surcharge: " + noOfWeekends * 10);
```

*P/s: You can opt to write a formula to calculate the number of weekends without a loop since we can derive the information from your current day and number of days left. Do give it a try.

Comment: where is the surcharge part?

Comment: added the changes, will be great if you can understand the code and learn something. i am sure you can understand the changes you need

Comment: Hi sihao, I was able to work it out before, sorry just replied now. This was for a Travel Agency Website.